# Change the default WordPress image on the dashboard login to a custom image

Tags: customization, login, wp-login-form

How do I change the default WordPress image on the dashboard login to a custom image?

[image]

Comment: Downvoted as you you clearly did not even try 30seconds worth of research. This topic has been handled tons of times on the net and this site. We are not here to do your researc for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload an image to your theme and add this to your functions:

```
add_action("login_head", "my_login_head");
function my_login_head() {
    echo "
    <style>
    body.login #login h1 a {
        background: url('".get_bloginfo('template_url')."/path to your image/logo-login.gif') no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
        height: 90px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    ";
}
```

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-login-picture